# "BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ESNext"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I installed React and TypeScript using `yarn create react-app my-app --typescript`.

Then I wrote this code:

```
import React from 'react';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const theBiggestInt = 9007199254740991n;
  return (
    <div>
   {"Durkurian"}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and got an error:

> BigInt literals are not available when targeting lower than ESNext.

What is the problem? How do I fix it?

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "24.0.17",
    "@types/node": "12.7.2",
    "@types/react": "16.9.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.8.5",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is [bigint is a new feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#Browser_compatibility). if you target an old version it won't be available. exactly like the error message says.

Comment: It seems I have not the old version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment, Bigint is a new feature.You cannot use BigInt while you have the target property in tsconfig.json in a value other than ESNext.But you shouldn’t do this because there is little browser support [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) and [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=bigint).

Comment: Why is this an issue though? Isn't tsc's job to transpile from TypeScript (which supports BigInt literals) to a given **target**? On a side note, it's funny because nodejs 12 supports these too

Comment: BigInt is enabled in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2020.bigint.d.ts` not `esnext`.

Answer (score 14):

`BigInt` is enabled in `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2020.bigint.d.ts`, so it is part of `es2020` not part of `esnext`.

However, it seems that the `***n` lexical expression is not part of `lib.es2020.bigint.d.ts`.  Indeed, that is enabled by `esnext`.

To enable typescript use with `BigInt` but without `****n` lexical expressions, this configuration worked:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
}
```

Adding "esnext" to the libs:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020", "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
}
```

then enables(*) the ability to '****n' lexical expressions.

(*) Another separate issue is that VSCode (if you are working with that) will sometimes opaquely enable '****n' as a valid expression, even when 'esnext' is never explicitly mentioned in the relevant `tsconfig.json` file.  Perhaps it is enabling `esnext` implicitly? That behavior is actually not helpful when trying to figure exactly what settings enable the `***n` lexical expressions - after adding `esnext` to a tsconfig file and *then removing it*, the abilty to use `****n` expressions continued anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `const theBiggestInt = BigInt(9007199254740991);` instead. I found out about this here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6907

The 9007199254740991n syntax is very new and isn't supported by create-react-app yet.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments below this answer BigInt(9007199254740991) is just alternative syntax for 9007199254740991n so this will not help you. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt for more details.

Perhaps try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/big-integer instead. It uses BigInt when it is available in a browser and when it isn't it acts as a polyfill.

Comment: Writing a that large integer literal (evaluating to a number) doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Bergi I was just using that as an example. I've changed it to the number the question originally asked for.

Comment: Doesn't matter which gigantic number it is. The interpreter will treat it as a Number literal as pass a Number (with lost precision) to the BigInt constructor.

Comment: @Paddy - Indeed `BigInt` is enabled in `es2020` and the `****n` expression is perhaps only enabled by `esnext`.  Your answer is therefore correct.  Thanks for sticking around despite the downvotes. +1

Comment: I wonder why TS does not transpile `0n` to `BigInt('0')` since it's the same thing?